# Weblogic t3/t3s over ssh tunnel

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, ssh-tunnel, wlst

I'm having trouble connecting to a weblogic server behind a firewall.

I can connect to the AdminServer using ssh tunnels, I can telnet into the adress and ports and right now it's accessible at https://127.0.0.1:25141/console/ or http://127.0.0.1:25101/console/.

Unfortunately I cannot connect to it ussing a WLST script.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   from wlstModule import *

username = 'weblogic' 
password = 'justsomepassword' 
URL='t3s://127.0.0.1:25141' 
connect(username,password,URL)
```

The error shown is:

> WLSTException: Error occurred while performing connect : Cannot connect via t3s or https. If using demo certs, verify that the -Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=DemoTrust system property is set. : t3s://127.0.0.1:25141: Destination 127.0.0.1, 25141 unreachable; nested exception is: 
>       javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; No available router to destination

Using t3 the exception is:

> WLSTException: Error occurred while performing connect : Error getting the initial context. There is no server running at t3://127.0.0.1:25101 : t3://127.0.0.1:25101: Bootstrap to: 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:25101' over: 't3' got an error or timed out while trying to connect to 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:25101

I've had this kind of problem in the past trying to connect any remote server to JDeveloper so I guess I'm missing some port forwarding. Is there any extra thing that i need to do in order to connect to a WLS behind firewalls?

Comment: Your firewall blocks your t3/t3s connections for security reasons. You can try to connect through http instead :  
`URL='https://127.0.0.1:25141' ` or configure http tuneling in weblogic.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the WebLogic startup scripts to allow T3 SSH tunnelling:

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dweblogic.rjvm.enableprotocolswitch=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true ${JAVA_OPTIONS}"
export JAVA_OPTIONS
```